# Tree-Tagger installed but error line. How to fix it?

Tags: unix, treetagger

I'm trying to install TreeTagger and the terminal gives me this output:
mkdir: cmd: File exists
mkdir: bin: File exists
mkdir: doc: File exists

TreeTagger version for ARM Linux 64 bit (HF) installed.
Tagging scripts installed.
awk: non-terminated string BIN="/User... at source line 1
context is
$0=="BIN=./bin"{print >>>  "BIN="/Users/rebeccaparrino/Documents/2a. <<<
awk: giving up

And it's repeated several times until it concludes with "Path variables modified in tagging scripts".

What does it mean? How can I fix it?